# Javascript window location in loop on masterpage

Tags: javascript

We have a site with masterpage. There is another page policy.aspx.

User has to accept the policy in order to access the site resources.

Hence we put the foll. code on masterpage. There is a boolean variable (`var boolVal`).

```
if(!boolVal)
 {
   window.location="http://url/policy.aspx";
 }
```

For new users boolVal is always false. So they get redirected to the policy.aspx page. But since this page also inherits the masterpage, it reloads continuously as it executes window.location again and again infinitely.

Can something be done besides stopping the policy.aspx page to inherit the masterpage?

Comment: I think you could check in the master page which the page url is and choose not to show the javascript code if it "policy.aspx" (or you name of the page).

Comment: So you want me to not run this part of js code if the page is policy.aspx

Comment: Well, yes - if the name of your policy page is "policy.aspx" and if it solves your problem (not easy to know since I don't have the complete code) :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without seeing the rest of your code, but my first instinct would be to change your code to:

```
if(!boolVal)
 {
   window.location="http://url/policy.aspx";
   boolVal = true;
 }
```

Comment: But then it will again get executed on the policy.aspx page as it inherits the master page. Are you getting my point?

Answer (score 0):

cut your js in 2 parts:
1 part with declaration.
1 part with the loop.
In `policy.aspx js` try to insert code between the 2 parties to change the value of the varialble boolVal

Answer (score 0):

Well, if JavaScropt is to blame, I bet problem lies in boolVal.
If it's not defined typeof boolVal is 'undefined'... Which is falsy value that you negate.

```
if(!boolVal) // will always be true if boolVal isn't defined/inherited properly.
```